# xcode 4.2.1 - custom keyboard - two UITextFields

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, uitextfield

I have created a custom keyboard and I have two text fields.

I am calling `[firstTextField becomeFirstResponder]` in my viewDidLoad

to have my keyboard visible.

How can I know which text field is currently active so that I write what the user is typing from the keyboard to the respected textField?

I have tried `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` but it is not being called

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `isFirstResponder` to determine which of your two UITextFields is currently active.

```
if ([firstTextField isFirstResponder]) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` to be called, you need to set the `delegate` outlets for both your text fields to whatever view controller (or wherever) the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method lives in.

You can set the delegates programmatically (e.g. `firstTextField.delegate = self;`) or via the XIB file.

And your intuition is correct, once `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` gets called, you will know (from the `textField` parameter) which field the user is currently typing in.